# How to get extra dimension value in shape (width, height, 3) from yuv frame

Tags: python, yuv

I have some code that reads some yuv frames and returns the separate components, I am trying to integrate this into some code which reads mp4 files and does some processing afterwards, the functions which are called depend on the shape being in the form (width, height,3), what is returned for the separate y u v components is just (width, height), so how would I be able to obtain the extra 3 in terms of the dimension and what sort of values are contained in this 3rd dimension? Everything done is in python

So my video is 1920,1080,

y, u, v = getComponents(video,60) #60 is frames

newFrame = modifyFrame(frames) # this is from the original code, and expects array shape of (1920,1080,3)

If I did print(y.shape) I'd get (1920,1080) without the 3rd dimension, I would need the input form to be in the form required by the modifyFrame method. Maybe it's possible to somehow combine the y, u, v components and get the third dimension I'm not sure in all honesty

Sorry if the answer might be obvious I'm new to all of this

Thanks

Comment: [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Added the lines of code I'm having problems with

Comment: It looks like the video frame format is YUV 420. I have posted a new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the dimensions, the video frame data format is [YUV 420](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y%E2%80%B2UV420p_(and_Y%E2%80%B2V12_or_YV12)_to_RGB888_conversion)

In order to convert 3 matrices `Y`, `U` and `V` from 420 format to 3 dimensional `YUV` matrix, you first need to resize `U` and `V` to be the same resolution as `Y`, and then stack them to 3D matrix.

Remark: YUV shape convention is (height, width, 3), as (1080, 1920, 3).

- For resizing you can use [cv2.resize](https://www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/opencv-python-resize-image/)
  Cubic interpolation is recommended (better quality than linear interpolation).
- For 3D stacking, you can use numpy [dstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) function.

Here is a code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Upscale u and v to be same resolution as y (1920 columns by 1080 rows)
u = cv2.resize(u, dsize=y.shape[::-1], interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)  # Use shape[::-1], to reverse the order of shape to be (cols, rows)
v = cv2.resize(v, dsize=y.shape[::-1], interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)

# Stack y, u, v in the third dimension
yuv = np.dstack([y, u, v])
```

Comment: Thanks for informing me on this, if I want to recompile the modified frames into a yuv video again would I have to return it to the original form it had or would writing the matrix to a binary file in the current form be sufficient? What I'm thinking though, wouldn't cubic interpolation affect the integrity of the results in that after I do the modifications (upsampling), I would need to do SSIM and PSNR to check the quality of output

Comment: Are you telling that `np.pad` works better than `resize`?

Comment: Upsampling U and V converts the format to YUV 444, you may continue working with YUV 444, or downscale U and V of `newFrame` back to 960x540. I don't know what the function `modifyFrame(frames)` does to the frame, but every frame processing affects the PSNR (it's not a sign for lower quality).

Comment: I have only looked at the output from the first part of the function (which needs input in this form) that doesn't require significant GPU memory, I will check how the frames will come out on a more capable pc and let you know what happens. Thanks for your help

Comment: Also, how would I be able to unstack the array to get the separate components again as I need everything to be in the 420 format afterwards

Comment: unstack: `y, u, v = np.dsplit(yuv, 3)`

Comment: So I've tried unstacking, however, it didn't work, the modify function returns a list of tensors, each tensor of shape (3, 1080,1920), so I thought I'd reverse the order separately for each using e.g.: a[0].shape[::-1] and convert to a numpy array, however, this only lead to there being an array which has a shape (3,) so when I tried to unstack, I got this, ValueError: dsplit only works on arrays of 3 or more dimensions

Comment: I've managed to sort out the issue,but I'm now only getting a green screen with nothing else displayed

Comment: Well... since I have no clue about `newFrame = modifyFrame(frames)`, I can't help you.

Comment: I have tried looking at the read/write process, so when upscaling u and v then writing to file a yuv 444 video is file, it works, as well as stacking,unstacking,reshaping back to 420 then writing, but doing modifications inbetween makes a solid green screen appear

Comment: Frame filled by zeros output a green screen. There is also a chance that values are in range [0, 1] (very close to zero) due to type conversion (float / uint8).

Comment: yes turns out the values had to be multiplied by 255 to convert back, thanks so much for all your help

Answer (score 3):

You can try.

```
>>> y.shape, u.shape, v.shape

((1920, 1080), (1920, 1080), (1920, 1080))
```

---

```
>>> frame = np.r_[y,u,v]
>>> frame = frame.reshape(-1,frame.shape[1],3)
>>> frame.shape
(1920, 1080, 3)
```

What it will do is it will stack the `y` `u` and `v` frames.
Hope that helps

You will have to either combine all the frames or call your function for each of the stacked yuv frame combination. That would depend upon your use case and performance requirements

**EDIT**

In case when your **Y**, **U**, **V** are having different shapes, try this.

```py
>>> y.shape, u.shape, v.shape
((1080, 1920), (540, 960), (540, 960))
```

---

```py
>>> u1 = np.pad(u, ((0, 540), (0, 960)), 'constant')
>>> v1 = np.pad(v, ((0, 540), (0, 960)), 'constant')
>>> u1.shape
(1080, 1920)
>>> v1.shape
(1080, 1920)
```

---

```
>>> frame = np.r_[y,u1,v1].reshape(-1,1920,3)
>>> frame.shape
(1080, 1920, 3)
```

**UPDATE**

To get back the values you can do

```
>>> y2 = frame.T[0]
>>> y2.shape
(1080, 1920)
>>> u2 = frame.T[1][0:540,0:960]
>>> u2.shape
(540, 960)
>>> v2 = frame.T[2][0:540,0:960]
>>> v2.shape
(540, 960)
```

And Btw, for the first part you could have also done the following which is lot easier :)

```
>>> u1 = np.pad(u, ((0, 540), (0, 960)), 'constant')
>>> v1 = np.pad(v, ((0, 540), (0, 960)), 'constant')

>>> frame = np.array([y,u1,v1]).T
>>> frame.shape
(1920, 1080, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, so when the yuv components are stacked, would this add the 3rd dimension by any chance?

Comment: Yes.  Check the shape. You can read about it [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html#numpy.r_)

Comment: (1080, 1920)
(540, 960)
(540, 960)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 265, in <module>
    frame = np.r_[y,u,v]
  File "/home/pc/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py", line 406, in __getitem__
    res = self.concatenate(tuple(objs), axis=axis)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 1920 and the array at index 1 has size 960

Comment: I get this basically, the first 3 are the shapes of the y,u,v components, do you know any workaround behind this?

Comment: I've tried stacking just the u and v to see what I would get and the size was (1080,960) which was weird in that only one dimension was stacked and there was no third dimension

Comment: Wouldn't normally y u and v be of same shape?

Comment: I checked and y = (width)(height) and u & v are (width/2)(height/2), so it fits in with what I'm getting

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't get any errors when applying this,  if I want to return everything back to the original layout after modifying the frame, how would I do that?

Comment: You can then slice the individual axis

Comment: So when doing the slicing, only the padded zeroes are removed or will some pixel intensity values be removed also?

Comment: only the padded zeros

Comment: Thanks so much for this, it is very appreciated :)

Comment: If it solved your problem you can accept the solution

Comment: @abhilb It looks like you fail to recognize that the video frame format is YUV 420.